# Probability $P(\mu - d\sigma < X < \mu +d\sigma) \ge 1-\frac 1 d^2$

Tags: probability, variance, confidence-interval

Show, that $P(\mu - d\sigma < X < \mu +d\sigma) \ge 1-\frac 1 d^2$ , when $\mu < \infty$ and $\sigma^2>0$ and $ d>1$

My Idea:

$P(\mu - d\sigma < X < \mu +d\sigma)$ = $1-P(X \ge \mu+d\sigma) + P(X>\mu-d\sigma) \ge 1- \frac {E[X^2]}{\mu+d\sigma} + P(X>\mu-d\sigma) \ge 1- \frac {E[X^2]}{\mu+d\sigma} = 1- \frac {\mu^2+\sigma^2}{(\mu+d\sigma)^2}$

I used the Chebyshev inequality and the formula for variance, but don't know how to proceed from here. Did I make a mistake? Or is it so obvious, that I just don't recognize it?

Comment: nothing stated about X? and are $\mu$ and $\sigma $ its parameter?

Comment: $X$ is any random variable and $\mu$ mean, $\sigma^2$ variance.

Comment: Are you able to solve now? If yes, please click the $\checkmark$ button by the answer to mark it accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(|X-\mu| \le d\sigma) = 1 - P(|X-\mu| > d\sigma)$$

$$P(|X-\mu| > d\sigma) \le \frac{\sigma^2}{d^2 \sigma^2} \quad \text{Chebyshev Inequality}$$